# Rails 4, Paperclip, AWS Image upload not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am making a rails app which has the ability for users to upload images. Right now it is working with just paperclip, and it saves images locally in my system/users.

Now, I want to be able to upload the images to S3. I have my bucket configured, and installed the `aws-sdk` gem, so the amazon side is down too.

I have read multiple sources online, but none of have worked so far. Here is what I currently have

**user.rb**

```
has_attached_file :image_1, 
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => Proc.new{ |amazon| amazon.instance.s3_credentials }
validates_attachment_content_type :image_1, :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "application/pdf"] }

has_attached_file :image_2, 
                  :storage => :s3, 
                  :s3_credentials => Proc.new{ |amazon| amazon.instance.s3_credentials }
validates_attachment_content_type :image_2, :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "application/pdf"] }

def s3_credentials
  {:bucket => "bucketname", 
   :access_key_id => "1234", 
   :secret_access_key => "1234"}
end
```

**aws.yml**

```
test:
  access_key_id: key
  secret_access_key: secret
development:
  access_key_id: key
  secret_access_key: secret
production: 
  access_key_id: key
  secret_access_key: secret
```

**development.rb, production.rb, test.rb**

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
   :storage => :s3,
   :s3_host_name => 's3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
 }
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def user_params 
  params.require(:user).permit(:image_1, :image_2)
end
```

**here is the stack trace when I submit the form **

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-08-17 19:20:14 -0700
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters{"utf8"=>"✓","user"=>{"recommendation_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8e4c9c8380 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/9c/1_0mk00n297f560_fpv9jzl40000gn/T/RackMultipart20150817-1642-1ituzt0.JPG>, @original_filename="20150520_DBC_519_L.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[recommendation_image]\"; filename=\"20150520_DBC_519_L.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "identification_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8e4c9c82e0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/9c/1_0mk00n297f560_fpv9jzl40000gn/T/RackMultipart20150817-1642-1mh7arc.JPG>, @original_filename="20150520_DBC_519_L.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[identification_image]\"; filename=\"20150520_DBC_519_L.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/9c/1_0mk00n297f560_fpv9jzl40000gn/T/594bb37e5dccc1de38e08bc3a4fe8b6e20150817-1642-g89xku.JPG'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/9c/1_0mk00n297f560_fpv9jzl40000gn/T/594bb37e5dccc1de38e08bc3a4fe8b6e20150817-1642-qx6l87.JPG'
```

I also read some resources that say I might need an initializer file, but that didn't seem to work either. If anyone has had some experience doing this, I would appreciate hearing your suggestion.

Comment: This question needs more detail. What's actually happening/not happening when you run this code? Any error messages?

Comment: Check AWS bucket permissions